# Can Netflix tell whether I am behind a VPN?

Tags: vpn, geolocation

I understand that if I [enable geolocation option in Firefox](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/16310/9308), then Netflix can learn where I am, and by comparing my actual location with my reported location, Netflix can deduce that I am behind a VPN.

> If you consent, Firefox gathers information about nearby wireless
>   access points and your computer’s IP address. Then Firefox sends this
>   information to the default geolocation service provider.

But let's say if I disable that, will Netflix ( or other webservices) still be able to know that I am hiding behind a VPN? If yes, how?

Comment: So your first question is what happens if you change your browser settings? Why not simply test it?

Comment: This question might help: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43768/can-someone-tell-if-you-are-using-a-vpn-by-your-ip-address

Comment: And this one too https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71774/how-can-i-detect-a-vpn-connection-even-just-in-some-cases-to-get-the-real-loca

Comment: FYI, I'm pretty sure Netflix can't use that information to find out where you are unless you give it permission.

On Chrome, when a website wants to find out your location a browser tooltip saying something along the lines of "Netflix.com wants to see your location. (Allow, Deny)" would appear. I'm pretty sure Firefox does something similar.

Comment: Netflix might simply lookup your IP with a list of known VPN IPs ...

Comment: @user78244, how to test? Even if you hide behind a VPN and Netflix doesn't complain about it, it doesn't mean that Netflix *doesn't* know about it, Netflix might still know, just don't bother

Comment: @Graviton I don't think they won't complain if they knew. In regards of geoblocking I don't think they would allow someone access to content if they knew that his location may be faked. If they would knowingly allow users access in such a case, I think that could get them in trouble with copyright owners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can't per se. But they can collect a list of the most popular known public VPN services and check if your IP matches with one of those VPN services. Whether they actually do that, I don't know.